# Un query que lance los horarios en horizontal y los médicos en vertical

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una duda de como se puede llegar a hacer un query que me ayude a tener la lista de doctores con sus especialidades, y tambien tener ala vez sus horarios pero que sus horarios por nombre del dia se muestre con con horas de 8 am hasta 8pm en un rango de 1 Hora y entender a que horas el doctor tiene cubierto recpecto a su horario.

[Reporte Manual](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XGSaCgPyoQpfJyTvjMDQAWyksthSACZF)

algo asi que aparece en la imagen pero en un query hasta ahora solo tengo esto:

```
    use  BI_SpringSalud_ProduccionQV

Select
Horario.IdHorario                   ,
Hora_Inicio_Horario     =   RIGHT(Horario.HoraInicio,7)         ,
Hora_Fin_Horario        =   RIGHT(Horario.HoraFin,7)            ,
Cita.IdMedico                       ,
Medico                  =   Medico.NombreCompleto               ,
Horario.IdEspecialidad              ,
Especialidad            =   Especialidad.Nombre                 ,
Horario.IdConsultorio               ,
Consultorio             =   Consultorio.Nombre                  ,
Descrip_Consultorio     =   Consultorio.Descripcion             ,
Ubicacion.IdUbicacion               ,
Ubicacion               =   Ubicacion.Nombre                    ,
Ubicacion_Descripcion   =   Ubicacion.RutaDescripcion           ,
Horario.IdTurno,
AtiendeLunes            =   Case when Horario.IndicadorLunes        = 2 Then 'S' Else 'N' End,
        AtiendeMartes           =   Case when Horario.IndicadorMartes       = 2 Then 'S' Else 'N' End,
        AtiendeMiercoles        =   Case when Horario.IndicadorMiercoles    = 2 Then 'S' Else 'N' End,
        AtiendeJueves           =   Case when Horario.IndicadorJueves       = 2 Then 'S' Else 'N' End,
        AtiendeViernes          =   Case when Horario.IndicadorViernes      = 2 Then 'S' Else 'N' End,
        AtiendeSabado           =   Case when Horario.IndicadorSabado       = 2 Then 'S' Else 'N' End,
        AtiendeDomingo          =   Case when Horario.IndicadorDomingo      = 2 Then 'S' Else 'N' End
--into #TMP_Cita
From 
SS_CC_Cita  Cita
    INNER JOIN SS_CC_Horario        Horario         ON  Cita.IdHorario          =   Horario.IdHorario
    LEFT JOIN SS_GE_Especialidad    Especialidad    ON  Horario.IdEspecialidad  =   Especialidad.IdEspecialidad
    LEFT JOIN PersonaMast           Medico          ON  Cita.IdMedico           =   Medico.Persona
    LEFT JOIN EmpleadoMast          IdCCostos       ON  Cita.UsuarioCreacion    =   IdCCostos.CodigoUsuario
    LEFT JOIN GE_CentroCostos       CCostos         ON  IdCCostos.CentroCostos  =   CCostos.CentroCostos    
    LEFT JOIN EmpleadoMast          CMP             ON  Medico.Persona          =   CMP.Empleado    
    LEFT JOIN PersonaMast           Paciente        ON  Cita.IdPaciente         =   Paciente.Persona
    LEFT JOIN SS_GE_Paciente        HC              ON  Paciente.Persona        =   HC.IdPaciente   
    LEFT JOIN SS_GE_Consultorio     Consultorio     ON  Horario.IdConsultorio   =   Consultorio.IdConsultorio
    LEFT JOIN SS_GE_Turno           Turno           ON  Horario.IdTurno         =   Turno.IdTurno
    LEFT JOIN SS_GE_TipoAtencion    TipoAtencion    ON  Cita.IdTipoAtencion     =   TipoAtencion.IdTipoAtencion
    LEFT JOIN SS_GE_GrupoAtencion   GrupoAtenc      ON  Cita.IdGrupoAtencion    =   GrupoAtenc.IdGrupoAtencion
    LEFT JOIN SS_GE_Servicio        Servicio        ON  Cita.IdServicio         =   Servicio.IdServicio
    LEFT JOIN SS_GE_Ubicacion       Ubicacion       ON  Consultorio.IdUbicacion =   Ubicacion.IdUbicacion   
    LEFT JOIN GE_EstadoDocumento    EstadoCita      ON  Cita.EstadoDocumento    =   EstadoCita.IdEstado AND EstadoCita.IdDocumento=45
where 
    Cita.UnidadReplicacion = 'ceg'  AND 
  YEAR(FechaCita)               = 2018  AND MONTH(FechaCita)= 09 and day(FechaCita) in (24,25,26,27,28,29)
    AND Cita.IdTipoAtencion         =   1
--  AND (Cita.IdGrupoAtencion       =   1 or cita.IdGrupoAtencion=2)
--  and Cita.IdMedico='179852'
--    and cita.IdCita = '5436366'
    -- AND Cita.Estado                  =   2 
  -- AND Paciente.NombreCompleto like 'RODRIGUEZ LINARES%'
  -- AND Cita.IdMedico=130577
  -- AND EstadoCita.Descripcion in ( 'ATENDIDO','ATENCION','PENDIENTE')
 --AND HC.IdPaciente = 1185704
 group by Horario.IdHorario , Medico.NombreCompleto, 
 RIGHT(Horario.HoraInicio,7), RIGHT(Horario.HoraFin,7), Cita.IdMedico,Medico.NombreCompleto,
Horario.IdEspecialidad, Especialidad.Nombre,
Horario.IdConsultorio, Consultorio.Nombre, Consultorio.Descripcion,
Ubicacion.IdUbicacion, Ubicacion.Nombre, Ubicacion.RutaDescripcion, Horario.IdTurno,
Case when Horario.IndicadorLunes        = 2 Then 'S' Else 'N' End,
Case when Horario.IndicadorMartes       = 2 Then 'S' Else 'N' End, 
Case when Horario.IndicadorMiercoles    = 2 Then 'S' Else 'N' End,
Case when Horario.IndicadorJueves       = 2 Then 'S' Else 'N' End,
Case when Horario.IndicadorViernes      = 2 Then 'S' Else 'N' End,
Case when Horario.IndicadorSabado       = 2 Then 'S' Else 'N' End,
Case when Horario.IndicadorDomingo      = 2 Then 'S' Else 'N' End
```

Comment: Añade la etiqueta del gestor que usas

Comment: Ya lo puse en el enlace puedes darle para que puedas entender a lo que quierollegar con un query de sql

Comment: Lo siento, pero no todos puedes acceder a enlaces externos. Todo lo referido a la pregunta debe ir en la pregunta, e incluye que base de datos estas usando. Y tene en cuenta que casi nunca un query debe solucionar un problema de la vista.

Comment: Si entiendo y dime, una consulta estoy usando Sql server  pero puedo obstener datos asemejantes que me ayude a obtener la informacion que requiero

Comment: o sino ay alguna manera de como desfragmentar el tiempo por ejemplo

Comment: un medico atiende desde las 2pm hasta las 8pm

Comment: como puedo yo decir que el medico esta habilitado mediante rangos asi

Comment: 'doctores '          '8-9'  '9-10'  '10-11'   '12-13'   '13-14'   '14-15'

'dr mendiola'       'no'      'no'       'si'        'si'        'si'         'si'

Comment: indicando que los si son las horas que cubre el doctor en su horario establecido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si entendí:

1. Tienes doctores que cumplen un horario, con una hora de inicio y otra de fin para cada uno
2. Además, 12 turnos (en tu imagen faltaría el turno de las 11 a 12) que inician desde las 8:00 hasta las 19:00
3. Los turnos tienen una duración de 1 hora
4. Quieres un consulta por Doctor que te muestre espacialmente la asignación de los 12 turnos.

Primero definimos un ejemplo para los horarios de cada doctor:

```
DECLARE @HorariosDoctores TABLE (
    Doctor      VARCHAR(100),
    HoraDesde   TIME,
    HoraHasta   TIME
)

INSERT INTO @HorariosDoctores (Doctor, HoraDesde, HoraHasta)
VALUES  ('Juan',  '08:00:00', '14:00:00'),
    ('Pedro', '12:00:00', '18:00:00'),
    ('Luis',  '09:00:00', '12:00:00'),
    ('Luis',  '16:00:00', '19:00:00')

SELECT  *
    FROM @HorariosDoctores


| Doctor | HoraDesde        | HoraHasta        |
|--------|------------------|------------------|
| Juan   | 08:00:00.0000000 | 14:00:00.0000000 |
| Pedro  | 12:00:00.0000000 | 18:00:00.0000000 |
| Luis   | 09:00:00.0000000 | 12:00:00.0000000 |
| Luis   | 16:00:00.0000000 | 19:00:00.0000000 |
```

Vemos que Juan comienza a las 8:00 y su último turnos es el que comienza a las 14:00, Luis en particular hace dos turnos de 9 a 13 y de 16 a 19

Lo siguiente que necesitaremos es una tabla de turnos, si no la tienes sería bueno que la crearas, sino puede construirse una de forma dinámica, lo que es importante es tener la hora de inicio de cada turno. Así sería si lo hacemos de forma dinámica:

```
SELECT  TMP.Turno,
    CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, TMP.Turno-1, '08:00:00') AS TIME) AS 'HoraInicio'
    FROM (SELECT 1 AS Turno UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) TMP

| Turno | HoraInicio       |
|-------|------------------|
| 1,00  | 08:00:00.0000000 |
| 2,00  | 09:00:00.0000000 |
| 3,00  | 10:00:00.0000000 |
| 4,00  | 11:00:00.0000000 |
| 5,00  | 12:00:00.0000000 |
| 6,00  | 13:00:00.0000000 |
| 7,00  | 14:00:00.0000000 |
| 8,00  | 15:00:00.0000000 |
| 9,00  | 16:00:00.0000000 |
| 10,00 | 17:00:00.0000000 |
| 11,00 | 18:00:00.0000000 |
| 12,00 | 19:00:00.0000000 |
```

Por último, si juntamos los horarios y los turnos, podremos agrupar esta consulta por doctor y lo único que haría falta es controlar para cada turno si el horario del doctor lo contempla:

```
SELECT  HD.Doctor,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.Turno = 1  THEN 'SI' ELSE '' END) AS T1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.Turno = 2  THEN 'SI' ELSE '' END) AS T2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.Turno = 3  THEN 'SI' ELSE '' END) AS T3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.Turno = 4  THEN 'SI' ELSE '' END) AS T4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.Turno = 5  THEN 'SI' ELSE '' END) AS T5,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.Turno = 6  THEN 'SI' ELSE '' END) AS T6,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.Turno = 7  THEN 'SI' ELSE '' END) AS T7,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.Turno = 8  THEN 'SI' ELSE '' END) AS T8,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.Turno = 9  THEN 'SI' ELSE '' END) AS T9,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.Turno = 10 THEN 'SI' ELSE '' END) AS T10,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.Turno = 11 THEN 'SI' ELSE '' END) AS T11,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T.Turno = 12 THEN 'SI' ELSE '' END) AS T12
    FROM @HorariosDoctores HD
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT   TMP.Turno,
                CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, TMP.Turno-1, '08:00:00') AS TIME) AS 'HoraInicio'
                FROM (SELECT 1 AS Turno UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11) TMP
        ) T
        on T.HoraInicio >= HD.HoraDesde AND T.HoraInicio <= HD.HoraHasta
    GROUP BY HD.Doctor


| Doctor | T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 | T5 | T6 | T7 | T8 | T9 | T10 | T11 | T12 |
|--------|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|-----|-----|-----|
| Juan   | SI | SI | SI | SI | SI | SI | SI |    |    |     |     |     |
| Luis   |    | SI | SI | SI | SI |    |    |    | SI | SI  | SI  |     |
| Pedro  |    |    |    |    | SI | SI | SI | SI | SI | SI  | SI  |     |
```

Comment: Cuando mencionas que si no hay una lista de turnos que lo haga en forma dinamica como es eso, por favor me podrias explicar.... ya que lo tengo es una lista de turnos pero como que horas predeterminadas 
`IdTurno Grupo TipoTurno HoraInicio HoraFinal Estado UsuarioCreacion FechaCreacion UsuarioModificacion FechaModificacion 
7 C N 12/05/2010 09:00:00 p.m. 12/05/2010 11:59:59 p.m. 2 MISESF 03/09/2008 12:29:25 p.m. ROYAL 12/05/2010 12:37:43 a.m.`

Comment: Cuando hablo de una lista de turnos, no hablo de la asignación de estos, sino de una tabla dónde defines de manera general que el turno 1 empieza a las 8:00, el 2 a las 9:00 etc. Esto puede que lo tengas en una tabla física o bien puedes generarlo dinámicamente como lo hice en mi respuesta.

Comment: Hola mauricio que puesto una erespuesta aqui mismocon el codigo que eh juntado con lo que me ayudaste pero me sale error :/ al momento de juntarlo osea entiendo que debo poner los campos que corresponde a mi tablas que se relacionan pero de ahi me sigue saliendo error

Comment: Y que error te dá?

Comment: Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Invalid column name 'HoraInicio'.

Comment: ¿Existe la columna `Medico.HoraInicio`?

Comment: No lo siento, ahora si puse mi antiguo query pero kla modifique ahora si

Comment: el que se muestra como comentario ese es pero me sale este error

Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: The multi-part identifier "T.HoraInicio" could not be bound.

Comment: Cambiaste el alias de la tabla dinámica de `T` a `TU`  revisa el código para que apunte al alias correcto.

Comment: Si lo cambie ya que lo que creaste de una tabla e forma dinamica tube que poner con respecto a mi tabla Turno ya que tiene las horas respectivas ya que donde esta el nombre doctor esta en la tabla Persona, y tengo que unirle un left join para juntarlos y por ende cambie tanto lo que me diste para darle formao estoy equivocado ???

Comment: Ya Patricio, ya funco xd lo que pasaba que no tenia que por que mover tu codigo enrealidadera adaptar con lostipos de mis campos ya que tu campo era horas minutos y segundos y el mio era fecha horas minutos y segundo lo converti a horas minutos segundos y ahi recien salio los datos que requeria

Comment: me puede ayudar a entender como se hace una tabla dinamica aqui esta el enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/209440/como-crear-una-tabla-dinamica-en-un-select-de-fechas-de-feriados-en-sql-server?noredirect=1#comment390620_209440

Comment: te acuerdas que creaste un 'select' de turnos ya yo quise hacer uno pero tener una tabla para las fechas de los feriados

Comment: @ChristianGuerraHuertas, podría seguir preguntándote para terminar de entender tu problema, pero esta forma no es el medio adecuado, además de que estaríamos un largo rato. Si tienes reputación suficiente podrías entrar a la sala de chat, si no, intenta definir una pregunta, con gusto trataré de ayudarte.

Comment: Si si tengo reputacion suficiente para entrar a chat pero como contactaria contigo directamente?

Answer (score 0):

Si los Horarios pueden ser finitos, puedes hacer subquerys por cada uno de ellos, al final casi siempre la vista crece es en vertical. claro debes medir el tiempo de respuesta del servidor